# Conic formulation with binary variables in Gurobi

Tags: optimization, math-software, integer-programming, binary-programming

I have a constraint of the following form

$$x^2 \leq yz$$

where $z$ is binary, $y \geq 0$, and $x$ is free. Can [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) handle this constraint?

Comment: They do quadratically constrained optimization.

Comment: This term "quadratically constrained optimization" unfortunately does not imply a specific type of optimization model. As far as I can see, the terminology is rather ambiguous in this domain.

Comment: Binary as in $\{0,1\}$? Or binary as in $\{\pm 1\}$? Are $x$ and $y$ real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (mixed integer) rotated quadratic cone. This can be handled in Gurobi.  See for instance http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/c_grbaddqconstr.html and https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/examples/qcp_py.html .

Alternatively, presuming there is a known upper bound for y, the right-hand side can be linearized per section 2.8 of "FICO MIP formulations and linearizations Quick reference" https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/examples/qcp_py.html, in which case it can be handled as a quadratic inequality constraint, plus the linearization constraints.